# Changing ordering of OS in GRUB

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, mint

I have recently installed Linux Mint along with my Ubuntu. The GRUB has replaced Mint as the default OS. How can I set Ubuntu as the OS that loads automatically again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot Ubuntu, open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t), and run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

PS: `dev/sda` would, almost always, be the correct device to use if Ubuntu is installed on a single internal hdd. In case you have more the one internal hdd, or if Ubuntu is installed on an external one, verify the correct device name by running `mount | grep ^/`.

Answer (score 1):

I used to edit grub's configuration files by hand back when Ubuntu used grub 1. I find grub 2's configuration files to be way too messy to try and learn all of their intricacies, so I simply use the available GUI programs instead.

I highly recommend `startupmanager` and/or `super-boot-manager`  (you might have to add a ppa for the latter).

Once installed, you simply fire up the GUI software and configure your grub (`super-boot-manager` can be also used to configure `burg`, which is a grub-based alternative with a some very good-looking themes). If all you want to do is change the default OS for booting, then all you have to do is select it from a roll-down list and press OK.

If you want to configure grub's config files directly, you're not supposed to be touching `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. That file is supposed to be generated automatically based on what's written in a slew of files in `/etc/grub.d/`. Editing `grub.cfg` does work, and it is the easiest (from the non-gui ways) quick and dirty solution, but it's discouraged because it will break once you update your kernel.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have needed to do this before, 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto/ChangeDefaultOS

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.